# Google Charts compound charts after deprecation

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

I am using [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) to draw **[compound charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/compound_charts)**, similar to the one depicted below (bar charts and line combined). Just learned that it [has been deprecated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.se/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html).

[image: Compound graph]

It seems the replacement is [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/), and I need to recode my stuff. But despite [my best search efforts](https://developers.google.com/search?q=compound%20chart) I can't find any examples or ways to make compound charts using the new API.

Is it possible to make compound charts with the new API? Anybody has a link to documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checkout Google Combo Charts
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

Comment: @C J: Great, can't remember having seen that before. Perhaps it's something Google has added recently. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to

1. Use Combo charts
2. repeat the data array and change it to the type you want.

   for instance,

use stacked bar charts and concat the data array before google visualization and use

```
seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {5: {type: 'line'}, {6: {type: 'line'}, .... }
```

and so on.
It's just a hack method. Or you can use some other JS chart libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
function priceChart(a) {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(a, true);
var options = {
   legend: 'none',
   bar: { groupWidth: '100%' },   // Remove space between bars.
  seriesType: 'candlesticks',
candlestick: {
      fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#a52714' }, // red
      risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#0f9d58' }   // green
   },
    series: {1: {type: 'line'},2: {type: 'line'}},
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById(vname));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.